# Liferay communication from view.jsp to myfile.js

Tags: javascript, jsp, liferay

I have proved to send an array between two portles writing communication code in the two view.jsp (sender and receiver) and all it's ok. 
Now I need to use this array in a file .js so I have send the array from view.jsp to myfile.js but this doesn't work.

In view.jsp(sender) I have wrote:

```
Liferay.fire('sendArray',{array: array});
```

In the myfile.js(receiver) I have wrote:

```
Liferay.on('sendArray',function(event) {

    console.log("Hello");
    array = (event.array);

 });
```

Comment: I have find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: It'd be friendly to others if you shared your solution. Or just deleted your question, so that nobody attempts to answer any more (instead of commenting)

Comment: Simply I have sent the array in the view.jsp of the receiver and I have invoked the function of myfile.js in view.jsp. Obviously I have built the function in myfile.js